# Laravel 5.3 Passport Models to use NeoEloquent

Tags: laravel-5, neoeloquent

Is there an easy way to override the Laravel 5.3 Passport Models so they would use `Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Model` instead of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try and bind it in your service provider in `register` method:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, \Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Eloquent\Model::class)
}
```